# Why can't I find a record in my test db even after creating it with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am writing a controller spec, and I am first creating an array of 3 `@users`. That looks like this:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when invited user IS an existing user' do
        before :each do
          @users = [
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user)
          ]
        end

        it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do
          login_user
          post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
          invited_user = User.find_by(email: controller.params[:email])
          expect(invited_user).to be_a(User)
        end
    end
end
```

When I run `rspec` with this test, it fails and gives me this error:

```
 1) Users::InvitationsController POST #create when invited user IS an existing user correctly finds User record of invited user
     Failure/Error: expect(invited_user).to be_a(User)
       expected nil to be a kind of User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, first_name: string, confirmation_token: string, confirmed_at: datetime, confirmation_sent_at: datetime, unconfirmed_email: string, invitation_relation: string, avatar: string, invitation_token: string, invitation_created_at: datetime, invitation_sent_at: datetime, invitation_accepted_at: datetime, invitation_limit: integer, invited_by_id: integer, invited_by_type: string, invitations_count: integer, bio: text, last_name: string, gender: integer)
```

Here is the Factory for `:user`:

```
  factory :user do
    association :family_tree
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password123"
    password_confirmation "password123"
    bio { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    invitation_relation { Faker::Lorem.word }
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now
    gender 1
  end
```

What is happening, I believe, is that the `User.find_by` ActiveRecord lookup is returning nil.

But if I created these 3 user records above, why would it return nil?

Comment: I don't see where you create users... You just build an array of user attributes (they are just hashes - not real users!) in before block. Method [`attributes_for`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) just return a hash which can be used to create user.

Comment: Can you post the `User` class? Do you know if your post is succeeding or failing?  You could be hitting a validation error. What user are you logging in with `login_user`? Additionally, as @gotva mentioned, you do not create users with the attributes call, the only create thing would be the post.